# PySpark: Converting Date String to Datetime Value in 1.6

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I working with Spark 1.6 and I want to convert a String Value to a Datetime Value. However, none of the suggestions I read here so far worked, it has probably to do with my old version and the weird datetime representation in my string.

It looks like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2011-11-17-12.00.46.841219',)], ['time'])

df.show(truncate = False)
```

How do I get a nice `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` datetime format? I tried [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp), but it did not work.

Best regards

Comment: you can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(<ts_column>, <ts_format>))`, but i believe you'll lose the fraction of seconds in the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(<ts_column>, <ts_format>))`, but I believe you'll lose the fraction of seconds in the conversion.

```
spark.createDataFrame([('2011-11-17-12.00.46.841219',)], ['ts_str']). \
    withColumn('ts', 
               func.from_unixtime(func.unix_timestamp('ts_str', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss'))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +--------------------------+-------------------+
# |ts_str                    |ts                 |
# +--------------------------+-------------------+
# |2011-11-17-12.00.46.841219|2011-11-17 12:00:46|
# +--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: It worked. Didn't know that you can specify your own custom format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_timestamp()` to convert a string to a timestamp with a custom format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp

df.withColumn(to_timestamp(col("time), "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS")).show()
```

Comment: [`to_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html#pyspark-sql-functions-to-timestamp) is available starting spark 2.2.0

Comment: my bad, I missed the version restriction.